# How to prevent Outlook from automatically rename of attachment files without extensions into ".dat" files while opening the EML file?

Tags: c#, outlook, smtp, mime, eml

I am trying to create programmatically in C# an EML file as a template for user to send some files using outlook.
Unfortunately, by specification, the file that should be sent, has no extension in the name, like "A0001".

The file I create looks like this:

```
X-Sender: sender@a.a
X-Receiver: receiver@a.a
X-Unsent: 1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Sender: sender@a.a
From: sender@a.a
To: receiver@a.a
Date: 14 Jul 2023 10:45:44 +0200
Subject: Subj
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary=--boundary_0_73a496c2-d154-4972-9044-2a98dc3d247e


----boundary_0_73a496c2-d154-4972-9044-2a98dc3d247e
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

RW1haWwgdGV4dA==
----boundary_0_73a496c2-d154-4972-9044-2a98dc3d247e
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="A0001"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="A0001"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64


ChQeKDI8RlBaZA==
----boundary_0_73a496c2-d154-4972-9044-2a98dc3d247e--
```

You can see, the attachment is named as "A0001". But, if I open the file in outlook it looks differently:

[image]

If I add the file extension, than it works as expected, with choosen extension.
If I add a dot to the end like "A0001." it is also being shown with a dot without "dat".
Unfortunately, I need to have the file with no extension and with no dots there.
By the way, if I remove the attachment in outlook and then attach it again manually by drag&drop, it looks great: no extension.

Is there any way to convince the Outlook not to add the ".dat" extension while opening the eml-file?

Thank you in advance!